# Why do deadlocks happen in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

So as I understand it, SQL deadlocks happen when a SPID is busy processing another query and it can't be bothered to run another one because it's so busy right now. The SQL Server "randomly" picks one of the queries to deadlock out of the resources asked for and fails it out, throwing an exception.

I have an app running ~ 40 instances and a back-end Windows Service, all of which are hitting the same database. I'm looking to reduce deadlocks so I can increase the number of threads I can runs simultaneously.

1. Why can't SQL Server just enqueue the new query and run it when it has time and the resources are available? Most of what I'm doing can wait a few seconds on occasion.
2. Is there a way to set **Transaction Isolation Level** globally without having to specify it at the onset of each new connection/session?

Comment: Your definition of `deadlock` is not correct. Normally SQL Server **does** let other requests wait. When it kills a query because it detects a deadlock condition it's because the given set of queries cannot complete (ever) and someone has to lose. I think if  you do a little reading on what deadlocks are, you'll be in a much better position to get value out of a better question

Comment: "So as I understand it" ...the rest of that paragraph is pretty much incorrect.

Comment: Deadlocks have nothing to do with the server being too busy to service a request. I suggest you either reword your question or go look up what a deadlock really is.

Comment: Your understanding of deadlock is wrong, but I think you have a good question.

Comment: lmao @heisenberg going HAM back in 2011...its okay tsilb I upvoted your terribly incorrect question. I mean really, who doesn't know what a deadlock is? **googles 'what is deadlock`**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your understanding of deadlocks is not correct. What you've described is blocking. It's a common mistake to equate the two.

A deadlock occurs when two separate transactions each want different resources and neither will release the one that they have so that the other can run. It's probably easier to illustrate:

SPID #1 gets a lock on resource A
SPID #2 gets a lock on resource B
SPID #1 now needs a lock on resource B in order to complete
SPID #2 now needs a lock on resource A in order to complete

SPID #1 can't complete (and therefor release resource A) because SPID #2 has it
SPID #2 can't complete (and therefor release resource B) because SPID #1 has it

Since neither SPID can complete one has to give up (i.e. be chosen by the server as the deadlock victim) and will fail.

The best way to avoid them is to keep your transactions small (in number of resources needed) and quick.

Comment: (+1) Imagine two cars headed towards each other on a single-lane road. They both need the road to continue on but obviously they both can't have it unless one car backs up or disappears (i.e. `rollback`). No amount of waiting, memory, disk, etc. can help

Comment: The SPIDs in question aren't even running proper transactions; simple CRUD statements only. Do I have to specify uncommitted on each one? 

Generally my app will open and close a connection for each statement/query, unless it has to do a bunch in a row. But they add up over the n threads and x users. Each statement/query (of the ones being deadlocked) only takes about 50-200ms to execute.

Comment: @tsilb you may find this [`aba_lockinfo`](http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/aba_lockinfo.html) utility to be very helpful

Comment: @tslib in SQL server every CRUD statement runs in a transaction.  That transaction can be implicit or explicit, but it always exists.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman Can I tell it not to lock the tables? I don't care whether my selects get the info before or after the update.

Comment: If you want more information on diagnosing deadlocks then a simple search on StackOverflow should turn up tons of information.

Comment: @tsilb That queestion is more complicated than it sounds at first glance.  As Tom H. suggests, you may want to search for deadlocks and also for "isolation levels".  Very briefly, you cannot tell it to not take a lock for commands that change data, but you can tell it on read operations to read through a lock using things like "With NOLOCK" query hint.  But this comes with risks attached and should be used very carefully.

Comment: @TomH., thanks for explanation. Do you have any links on more detailed info about deadlock, want to learn them detailed.

Answer (score 3):

Deadlock is where two threads of processing are both being held up by the other ( it can be more, but two is sufficiently complex ). So one thread locks a table, then requests a lock on another table. the other table is locked by the second thread, which cannot progress because it is waiting for a lock on the first table.

The reason that one of these has to be thrown out is that in a deadlock, they will never end - neither thread can progress at all. The only answer is for one to be stopped to allow the other to complete.

The solution to reducing deadlocks in the sort of situation you are talking about may be to redesign the solution. If you can make sure that less locking occurs, you will have less deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlocks occurs because, two concurrent transactions may overlap e lock different resources, both required by the other transaction to finish.

Let's imagine:
1 - Transaction A locks row1
2 - Transaction B locks row2
3 - Transaction A tries to lock row1, and, because of the previous lock, SQL server waits
4 - Transaction B tries to lock row2, and, because of the previous lock, SQL server waits

So, SQL server must choose on transaction, kill it, and allow the other to continue.

This image ilustrates this situation very well: http://www.eupodiatamatando.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/deadlocknajkcomafarialibh3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The replies are correct about the classic deadlock problem, but there's one more cause of deadlocks, called "lock escalation", that can happen even if all threads follow the same order of updates, and it's usually raised on SELECT statements.

This is brought up on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826748/7268905

But basically, 2 concurrent threads can issue a SELECT on the same table, which places a shared lock. Then one of the thread issues an UPDATE on that table, and it causes the shared lock on the table to be promoted to an exclusive lock, but there's a shared lock already from another thread, and this causes an instant deadlock. SQL Server will choose the shared lock (SELECT) as the deadlock victim, to allow the UPDATE to continue.

The usual fix for this type of deadlocks is to add a hint on the SELECT statements for the tables involved in later UPDATEs, to make the lock exclusive instead of shared, preventing a concurrent SELECT statement from another thread to place a shared lock on it.