# Will 2 select statements cause deadlock to each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

My understanding is 2 select statements will not cause deadlock to each other.

Recently, I got an error in my code. It happened maybe once or twice a week. I got a deadlock error when my code tries to query a view. The table is maintained by a third party application. We are not allowed to modify it. We just query the data via a view created from that table.

My understanding is even I have multiple threads querying this view. It won't cause the deadlock. I am sure that the rows I am querying will never be updated. So the deadlocks here can only be caused by multiple select statements?

If so, is there a way to overcome this issue?
I have read the post [Transaction deadlock for select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826600/transaction-deadlock-for-select-query).
I am using sql server 2008. There is no extended events in 2008. There is no solutions for this issue in that post? Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `SELECT` statements should not be exclusively locking resources, so they should not result in deadlocks.

Comment: Worth a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826600/transaction-deadlock-for-select-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transaction deadlock for select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826600/transaction-deadlock-for-select-query)

Comment: The fact that you're querying rows that won't be updated doesn't necessarily mean your view won't be the victim of a page lock or table lock taken by an update to other rows. Not helpful, but it could be what's happening.